# Wordpress function overrides all menu's

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site and I got the following problem:

To have a different menu for those who are logged in, I use the following code:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

In the footer, there's another menu, but due to the code above, it gets changed to the logged-in or logged-out menu.

I made 2 other menu's, called `bottom-logged-in` and `bottom-logged-out`, and I want to use the same code to change the menu in the footer to those 2 menus.

I'm using visual composer and added the class `vertical-menu-custom` to the menu used for the footer.

**Edit:** I thought maybe it is possible to write another if/else statement to check if the menu is in the `vertical-menu-custom` div, and then use the current code 2 times: 1 for the menu that isn't inside the `vertical-menu-custom`, and 1 for the menu which is. And then of course change menu names to the menu's for the footer.

Comment: we need more information to solve this issue.

Comment: Well I don't know which other information I need to provide. I thought maybe it is possible to write another if/else statement to check if the menu is in the `vertical-menu-custom` div, and then use the current code 2 times: 1 for the menu that isn't inside the `vertical-menu-custom`, and 1 for the menu which is. And then of course change menu names to the menu's for the footer.